# Image inside a link. IE draws borders around an image. How to remove borders?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a following code:

```
    <a href="/Default.aspx" style="border: none;"><asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image1.png" /></a>

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink559" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image1.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
```

It's an image inside (of?) a link to my default web-site page.

It looks good in Opera and Chrome, but in internet explorer it draws a borders around an images. How to remove those borders ?

I'm a little bit confused with appropriate tag, so please correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
img {
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Paramasivan, it works. I didn't know about outline property. Gone read for additional information!

Comment: Altough @Paramasivan's answer is correct, please consider not to remove the outline even tho it looks bad on some browsers there's a accessibility reason. Read more about it [here.](http://www.outlinenone.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your page

```
<style>
    img{
       border:none;
       outline:none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `asp:Image tag` inside `Hyperlink`, Hyperlink has a property to add the image. So result will be image tag wrapped around anchor.
USe something like this:

**Aspx:**

```
     <asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink559" 
              ImageUrl="images/pict.jpg"
              NavigateUrl="http://www.microsoft.com"
              Text="Microsoft Official Site"
              Target="_new"
              runat="server"/>
```

**CSS**

```
   a img{
          border: none;
          outline: none;
    }
```

Comment: Ani, first code with ImageUrl don't remove a borders in internet explorer. I use answer of Paramasivan. You need to add outline property in CSS to make it work.

Comment: Sure...but i saw you were doing the aspx wrong. Added that ...thanks